Copy a message from a discord channel and send it to another program
How do I write a function inside a class that will return a message from a discord channel. I need to store that message in a variable to send it to another program.
This is the class:
 import discord
 import asyncio

 class MyClient(discord.Client):

 async def on_message(self, message: discord.message.Message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    print(message.id)
    if message.author.id == self.user.id:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$'):
        content= message.content
        print('Content: ', content) //this print works
        return content


defIntents = discord.Intents.default()
defIntents.members = True
defIntents.message_content = True
client = MyClient(intents=defIntents)
client.run("xxxxxx")

This is the part that is not working so far: calling the function on_message()and store the returned value in the variable returned_message
returned_message = asyncio.run(client.on_message())
print("returned message: ", returned_message)

